# Connection Timeouts on OSRM Server

Tags: python, optimization, openstreetmap, osrm

First of all: I am now to this world and I am using Google Colab.
After this I will start explain:
I am writing a thesis and a part of the thesis is about writing a code for last mile simulation.
I am using OSRM service to obtain distances and route durations between different points.
Till last night it was perfect and worked with my dataset of 80 points (3160 possible pairs).
Now I gives this error:

TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectTimeoutError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7a8cf0489210>, 'Connection to router.project-osrm.org timed out. (connect timeout=None)')

What can I try? Is it a OSRM problem and I cant do nothing?

I tried with a smaller dataset and it works (10 points) but I noticed it is very slow compared to before.
I also tried to divide the all possible pairs in different batch but it still does not work.

Comment: There are various OSRM instances: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Open_Source_Routing_Machine#Services_and_applications_powered_by_OSRM. Maybe try a different one? Alternatively, you can also install your own, local OSRM server.